# How to style more than one ul

Tags: html, css

I'm using the CSS lines below for a menu on a webpage.

The problem is that I don't know how to make that code apply only to the menu, and not to other ul -unordered lists- on the page!

```
ul {
text-align: left;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
}

ul li {
font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: -4px;
position: relative;
padding: 15px 20px;
background: #AAF7BB;
font-size: 110%;
}

ul li:hover {
background: #ffffff;
color: #000000;
}
ul li ul {
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 48px;
left: 0;
width: 150px;  
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
ul li ul li { 
background: #ffffff; 
display: block; 
color: #00ff00; 
}

ul li ul li:hover { background: #ffffff; }

ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible; 
}
a:link {
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you share your html as well?

Comment: None of the suggestions so far seem to work!

Comment: I mean can someone actually edit the code I have to make it work? I basically would like that CSS not to interfere with the default (or other) UL styling on that page.
I am really starting to despise the whole idea of CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned you can do this using classes on your html. I would try and Google this a little more. There are tons of example for menus out there. 
In the top three is this:

http://www.noupe.com/essentials/freebies-tools-templates/100-great-css-menu-tutorials.html

Something simple:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-option">
        <a href="link1">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-option active">
        <a href="link2">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-option">
        <a href="link3">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <a>Something to click</a>
        <li class="menu-option">
            <a href="link3">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-option">
            <a href="link3">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Your css would need to be updated similar to below

```
ul.menu:{
    /*Your style for the menu*/
}

ul.menu li.menu-option:{
    /*Your style for the menu's options*/
}

ul.menu ul.sub-menu:{
    /*Your style for the menu's sub-menu's*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try marking your ul as a class and refer to that instead of just ul.

```html
<ul class="menu">
```

and change all instances of ul in the css to .menu.

Refering to just "ul" will apply the change to all ul elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `class` or `id` attributes alongside your `HTML` elements. For example:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="class1">
...
</ul>

<ul class="class1">
...
</ul>

<ul id="class2">
...
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```css
.class1{
    implement css styling here
}

#class2{
    implement css styling here
}
```

Here, the top 2 `ul` elements will be styled by the `.class1` CSS styling, the final `ul` with the attribute `#class2` will be styled by the corresponding CSS.

Note that `.` denotes classes in `CSS` and `#` denotes `IDs`

`IDs` are unique, `classes` are not unique.  [More information](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)